# Symfony web debugging toolbar for dev environment occasionally fails on staging server

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, environment-variables, symfony

On our staging server I have infrequent problems loading the web debug toolbar for Symfony3.

Once in approximately every 5 page loads I get the following `alert()` (see screenshot):

[image]

There's no problem with the page itself, all of my src code is running fine but since `alert()` halts all browser execution it gets a bit annoying.

Since I don't have the same setup locally, I have one suspicion that it could refer to the way I've setup the project on the staging server specifically.

Locally, I have one `<VirtualHost>` entry. Here take a look:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bvd-v3.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/apple/projects/mentel/bvd-v3/web"
    #SetEnv SYMFONY__ACCESS__LEVEL admin
    SetEnv SYMFONY__ACCESS__LEVEL user
    <Directory "/Users/apple/projects/mentel/bvd-v3/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And as you might expect I simply change which environment variable is commented out and re-start Apache when I want to load the admin portal instead of the user portal, and vice versa.

On the staging server, at the moment, it's been easier for me to manage the project by creating 2 vhost entries each pointing to the same `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` (i.e. using the same source code) but each Vhost has a different URL and a different environment variable value for `SetEnv SYMFONY__ACCESS__LEVEL`

Could this be the problem? Or would it be something else? I'm asking because I don't have permissions to access the Vhost conf on the staging server and need to get one of the Sysadmins at our office to make the change, so I don't want to get him to do something for no reason and also that forces me to update 2 independent versions of the source code cause if he does it for me he might not want to change it back for me lol.

Thanks all, any insight is appreciated.

Comment: After playing around a bit, it seems to only happen if I wait a really long time to refresh or navigate to a page. I just clicked refresh about 20 times in a row and I never saw the error.

Comment: Feel free to make your own tests, the 2 vhosts are public facing at: 1) http://user-portal.bvdv3.qa.mentel.ca/ 2) http://admin-portal.bvdv3.qa.mentel.ca/

It seems to happen most often on the home page or '/' route.

Comment: sessions timming out perhaps

Comment: I think the cache directory is having permissions problems because the sysadmin set it up not me: `web6@isp3:/var/www/clients/client3/web6/web/admin_portal/bvd$ chmod -R a+rwX var/cache/
chmod: changing permissions of ‘var/cache/de~/annotations/31/5b4256445c4d656e74656c42756e646c655c436f6e74726f6c6c65725c5265706f727473436f6e74726f6c6c6572235f5f636f6e737472756374405b416e6e6f745d5d5b315d.doctrinecache.data’: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Is there a reason this question was voted down?

Answer (score 0):

Is this MacOS X? If so, Symfony says to use this to set the var permissions:

```
$ rm -rf var/cache/* var/logs/* var/sessions/*

$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo chmod -R +a "$HTTPDUSER allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" var
$ sudo chmod -R +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" var
```

See this link:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup

I didn't downvote you. I think it's sad when people downvote without giving a good comment, and I don't see that. I will upvote, because you've given a lot of information.

I also noticed when using Firefox to debug (select inspect element and refresh the page), I see this:

GET XHR  http://user-portal.bvdv3.qa.mentel.ca/_wdt/d68325

Notice it's a XHR request, maybe that'll clue you into the problem.

**Edit #2**
For Ubuntu, you'll need to use these commands to set the var permissions:

```
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
```

Comment: The server is Ubuntu 14.04. That's interesting, I didn't realize it was an XHR I think that does give a clue as Symfony says it's a token error if I press ok on the javascript alert (which navigates to a debugging view). I'm going to take a look into the CSRF settings. Thanks!

Comment: I edited (Edit #2) my post to show what you would use for Ubuntu. This would address any permission problems with the var directory.

Comment: Thanks I will test out your suggestions and report back